# Disable syntasic html/tidy checker for a file

Tags: vim, syntastic

Is there a way to disable the html/tidy plugin for syntastic for a certain file?

I have a handlebars template that contain an empty `<tbody></tbody>` tag as a placeholder, and I keep getting the error
`trimming empty <tbody> [html/tidy]`

Is there a way to either disable this specific rule, or just disable the html/tidy plugin for this specific file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to put this in your .vimrc

```
let g:syntastic_html_tidy_ignore_errors=[" proprietary attribute " ,"trimming empty <", "unescaped &" , "lacks \"action", "is not recognized!", "discarding unexpected"]
```

This solves more things than one but I think it can be helpful. More on this [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/HTML:---tidy#checker-options).

Comment: Thanks for the list of rules! Any way I could put these in a config file for the project instead?

Answer (score 6):

I was running into this with `.hbs` and `.html` templating for a node project. Adding this to my .vimrc helped:

```
let syntastic_mode_map = { 'passive_filetypes': ['html'] }
```

more options here https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/240

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, if you just want to turn warnings off for html tidy:

```
let g:syntastic_html_tidy_quiet_messages = { "level" : "warnings" }
```

I have found this is a welcome setting for editing twig templates.

Of course for more info, in vim:

```
:h syntastic-checkers
```